# How do I print on a canon USB printer connected to Windows 10 from Ubuntu over LAN

Tags: windows, printing, samba

I have a canon printer connected to a desktop machine at my office. we are two in that office and we share everything together. its practically two machines with freely shared resources, NO RESTRICTION OR AUTHENTICATIONS.

The bad news is I switched to Ubuntu and now I can access every drive on the Windows and delete and do everything but the Windows can see me on the network but cant access the Ubuntu. how do I get around that, I need no permissions of nothing for the Windows user to access mine just as I easily access his.

Also I can't print on the Windows printer. I have the drivers and when I connect the printer directly to the Ubuntu it prints just fine, but it can't go through Windows to print even though the printer is shared. Ihave installed samba but don't know what to do next? please help.